# Woocommerce postcode field placeholder

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Adding placeholder to Postcode billing field in Woocommerce.

In core class-wc-countries.php

```
'postcode' => array(
                'label'        => __( 'Postcode / ZIP', 'woocommerce' ),
                'required'     => true,
                'class'        => array( 'form-row-last', 'address-field' ),
                'clear'        => true,
                'validate'     => array( 'postcode' ),
                'autocomplete' => 'postal-code',
            ),
```

So there is no way to override it woocommerce_billing_fields filter. Why some fields have placeholder key but other not? Some fields have only labels, some only placeholders and some have both. I don't get logic behind this.

So my question is: how to add placeholder text to Postcode field. I can do it with Javascript, but that seams not natural. Also I can modify core, which is even worse then Javascript solution. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below code into your function.php for adding/updating postal code for checkout and edit screen.

```
//on edit address screen

function filter_woocommerce_billing_fields( $wooccm_billing_fields, $int ) { 

    $wooccm_billing_fields['billing_postcode']['placeholder'] = __('My Post Code', 'woocommerce');;

    return $wooccm_billing_fields; 
};              
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'filter_woocommerce_billing_fields', 10, 2 ); 


add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'update_placeholder_checkout_form_billing');
function update_placeholder_checkout_form_billing($wcCheckout_fields) {
    $wcCheckout_fields['billing']['billing_postcode'] = array(
        'label' => 'Postcode / ZIP',
        'placeholder' => _x('My Post Code', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required' => true,
        'class' => array('checkout-billing-postal-code')
    );
    return $wcCheckout_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Ash Patel we can do it like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', function($fields){

    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['placeholder'] = __('My Post Code', 'woocommerce');

    return $fields;

} );
```

And for shipping

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', function($fields){

    $fields['shipping_postcode']['placeholder'] = __('My Post Code', 'woocommerce');

    return $fields;

} );
```